# Who did she fall in love with?

Tags: questions

Is that question only about the past or that question may be asked also about the current situation? As I understand it, for present situation is *"Who is she in love with?"*.

> Who **did** she fall in love with?

Comment: For the present situation , you could say "Who has she fallen in love with?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it like this: Whether she fell in love a long time ago or she fell in love one hour ago, it still happened in the past. Therefore, asking "Who did she fall in love with?" is not grammatically incorrect to use in either case.

I hope I answered your question sufficiently. :)